# trouble placing JSONP $.ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

My JSONP request is not working properly

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function call_back(data){
                console.log("In callback function");
                console.log(data);
            }


            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.test.net",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'call_back',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: { user: 'myusername', password: 'mypassword'}
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

which results in the error

```
{"error": "Missing user and/or password POST parameters"}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats on the end point? That looks like an error from the server and not jquery.

Comment: Check out your request in Chrome's Developer tools or Firebug on Firefox.  Does your request look like it should according to your JSONP provider?  Also, it would be helpful to know what JSONP service you're calling, since as travis noted it's a server error (not jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP only supports `GET` requests. This is due to it using a `<script>` rather than an `XMLHttpRequest` to make the request.

To perform an `POST` request to a cross-origin resource, the remote server will have to [permit requests with CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript#Cross-origin_network_access) or you'll have to create a proxy script on your own server.